# How to Run Python tags through Textarea

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have setup wagtail CMS application and i have build one snippets that have field "title" as `charField`,`key-word` as `charField` and `content` as `TextBlock`.

I've created one record with value:

```
 title : "header"
 key-word: "header-design"
 content : "<div><img src="{% static 'src/logo.png' %}" /><span class="slug">Slug Text</div>"
```

When I open in browser it show image python script as it is instead of output path of image.

```
{% get_contentholder "Logo Holder" as header_part %}
{{header_part | safe }}

{% get_contentholder "Logo Holder" as header_part %}
{{header_part | safe }}

<div>
  <img src="{% static 'src/logo.png' %}" />
  <span class="slug">Slug Text
</div>
```

Comment: content is like this  in textarea  <div><img src="{% static 'src/logo.png' %}" /><span class="slug">Slug Text</div>

Comment: Don't do this. The whole point of a CMS like Wagtail is to provide a separation between the editors who are writing content, and the developers who are writing code. If your users are writing template code inside the CMS, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I have seen kind of application in wagtail / django that store partial of header footer by textarea to manage direct from backend instead of doing any changes to header coding  page file.  that is why i am looking for solution of this.

Comment: Why won't you use separate fields? I've seen developers set it up like that and it works perfectly.

Comment: I want to manage few things by editor / textarea. issue it {{ my text area content }}
so it becomes {{ {{}} }} twice and ouput tags instead of content.